# "What language is this?" Or "What is this language?"

Tags: word-order, questions

> What language is this?

Or

> What is this language?

Which sentence is grammatically right or are both of them right but just with different meanings?

Comment: Similar https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/179671/what-color-is-your-car-vs-what-is-the-color-of-your-car

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct, such that;

1. What [Adjective Determiner (Interrogative)] language is this [Pronoun Determiner (Demonstrative)]?
2. What [Pronoun Determiner (Interrogative)] is this [Adj. Determiner (Demonstrative)]] language?

I think, in the first question, the word **language** is emphasized more than it is in the second one.